# Custom SKPhysicsJoint Subclass

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicsjoint

I'm currently working with `SKPhysicsJointSpring` to connect a number of nodes together.  I'd like to be able to specify the force using a logarithmic formula, rather than Hooke's law.

Is there a way for me to subclass `SKPhysicsJoint` to provide my own force calculations?  Or must I implement this manually in `update(..)`?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement it “manually in `update`”, or some other way. `SKPhysicsJoint` and its apparent subclasses aren't even real. Try printing one:

```
:; xcrun swift -framework SpriteKit
"crashlog" and "save_crashlog" command installed, use the "--help" option for detailed help
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.0 (700.0.52.1 700.0.65). Type :help for assistance.
  1> import SpriteKit
  2> print(SKPhysicsJoint())
<PKPhysicsJoint: 0x1029006b0>
  3> print(SKPhysicsJointSpring())
<PKPhysicsJointDistance: 0x102800530>
```

You actually get instances of classes from the private PhysicsKit framework, and you can't subclass those classes.